# Script to look at files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a script that shows all the files in a directory named "Trash". The script will then prompt the user for which file he wants to "undelete" and send it back to it's original directory. Currently I am having a problem with the for statement, but I also am not sure how to have the user input which file and how to move it back to it's original directory. Here is what I have thus far:

```
PATH=/home/user/Trash
for files in $PATH
do
  echo "$files deleted on $(date -r $files)"
done
echo "Enter the filename to undelete from the above list:"
```

Actual Output:

```
./undelete.sh: line 6: date: command not found
/home/user/Trash deleted on
Enter the filename to undelete from the above list:
```

Expected Output:

```
file1 deleted on Thu Jan 23 18:47:50 CST 2014
file2 deleted on Thu Jan 23 18:49:00 CST 2014
Enter the filename to undelete from the above list:
```

So I am having two problems currently. One instead of reading out the files in the directory it is giving $files the value of PATH, the second is my echo command in the do statement is not processing correctly. I have changed it around all kinds of different ways but can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making many mistakes in your script but biggest of all is setting the value of reserved path variable `PATH`. Which is basically messing up standard paths and causing errors like `date` command not found.

In general avoid using all caps variables in your script.

To give you a start you can use script like this:

```
trash=/home/user/Trash
restore=$HOME/restored/
mkdir -p "$restore" 2>/dev/null

for files in "$trash"/*
do
  read -p "Do you want to keep $file (y/n): " yn
  [[ "$yn" == [yY] ]] && mv "$file" "restore"
done
```

Comment: Changing the PATH variable fixed the date problem like you mentioned. Can you explain what exactly the /* on the end of "$trash" is saying? It will work but it gives the full path and not just the file name. How do I get rid of the file path? Example:/home/user/Trash/trashfile deleted on Fri Feb 28 23:07:33 CST 2014

Comment: You can use `f=$(basename "$file")` to get just the filename without path. `*` is matching (using glob) all the files in trash directory for looping.

Comment: I just realized that my date command at the end only shows the creation date. Is there a command to show the date it was moved? I Know ls -lc shows the move date with extra stuff in it, but if I just wanted the date only, is there a command for that?

Comment: I have used stat -c%z myfile3 | cut -d' ' -f1,2 which gives me the date and time changed, but is it possible to convert it to the same format as the date -r option? so like Thu Jan 23 etc etc etc...

Comment: Use `stat -c%Z myfile3` to get date-time in EPOCH value and then display it in anyway you want using `date -s` command.

Comment: In that case you should close this close by marking it as accepted since it answered your original question perfectly fine. For all subsequent questions you can focus on new thread.