# MV command giving me are the same file error

Tags: linux, shell

So I am building this script to take a file from the "trash" directory and move it to the home directory. I am getting an error mv:/home/user/Trash/ and /home/user/Trash are the same file. The problem is I am moving the file to /home/user. I can't figure out why it is giving me this error.

Script:

```
trash="/home/user/Trash"
homedirectory="/home/user/"
for files in "$trash"/*
do
echo "$(basename $files) deleted on $(date -r $files)"
done
echo "Enter the filename to undelete from the above list:"
read $undeletefile
mv $trash/$undeletefile $homedirectory
```

Output:

```
myfile2 deleted on Thu Jan 23 18:47:50 CST 2014
trashfile deleted on Fri Feb 28 23:07:33 CST 2014
Enter the filename to undelete from the above list:
trashfile
mv: `/home/user/Trash/' and `/home/user/Trash' are the same file
```

Comment: Use `set -x` (or start your script with `bash -x scriptname`) to see which commands your script is running, and the reason for this error should become obvious.

Comment: Didn't you ask this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161083/script-to-look-at-files-in-a-directory ?

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest running this through http://shellcheck.net/ and following its advice before bugging humans; there are a number of issues here which can be trivially found through static checking.

Comment: @anubhava I asked a similar question about this script but someone told me I should make a new question because the code had changed so much and it wasn't anything like the original question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the advice about shellcheck.net didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `read` command. You are not supposed to add `$` to it.
Try:

```
read undeletefile
```

Comment: If you want to add a reference, that would be BashPitfalls #14: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#read_.24foo

Comment: ...that said, while you've identified an issue, this isn't the only problem in the script (a rather long way from it, rather).

Comment: Thanks that moved it properly, I knew it had to be something simple I just couldn't figure it out.